# No such element in map, why?

Tags: java, generics, collections

I am working on a code in which if I try **arrays** everything works fine but when i try to solve that example with list it displays

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.delete.files.DeleatingFiles.check(DeleatingFiles.java:27)
    at com.delete.files.DeleatingFiles.main(DeleatingFiles.java:60)
```

and the code is :

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        File folder = new File("F://fileIO/");
        if (folder.isDirectory()) {
            List<File> filesName = Arrays.asList(folder.listFiles());
            Iterator<File> itList = filesName.listIterator();
            while (itList.hasNext()) {
                map.put(itList.next().getName(), itList.next().toString());
            }
            System.out.println(map);
                }
        } else {
            System.err.println("something is wrong");
        }
    }
```

EDIT 1: All I am trying is to save file name with absolute path as key value pair. 
EDIT 2: can't use as `String`next=itrList.next() as **Iterator is of File type**.

Now , can anyone tell me the cause of problem ??
Please tell me if there is something wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `map.put(itList.next().getName(), itList.next().toString());` call next() twice even you check `itList.hasNext()` once.

```
while (itList.hasNext()) { // Check once
   map.put(itList.next().getName(), itList.next().toString()); // next() Call twice here
}
```

Your code may have to be corrected as like follows

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    File folder = new File("F://fileIO/");
    if (folder.isDirectory()) {
        List<File> filesName = Arrays.asList(folder.listFiles());
        Iterator<File> itList = filesName.listIterator();
        File file;
        while (itList.hasNext()) {
            file = itList.next();
            map.put(file.getName(), file.toString());
        }
        System.out.println(map);
    } 
    else {
        System.err.println("something is wrong");
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code calls `next` twice, so if `itList` has an odd number of elements, the last call would result in `NoSuchElementException`.

Here is how you can fix your code:

```
while (itList.hasNext()) {
    // Call "next()" once
    File next = itList.next();
    // Use "next" as many times as you need
    map.put(next.getName(), next.toString());
}
```

> is there any other way i can do that without using array?

You can simplify iteration considerably by switching to "for-each" loop:

```
if (folder.isDirectory()) {
    for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
        map.put(file.getName(), file.toString());
    }
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

Now your code does not create unnecessary copies of lists, and is free of the `NoSuchElementException` bug.

Comment: thanks for reply . i already tried that as because List and iterator is type of File , so cant do that.

Comment: @PankajPathania Ah, you are right, `next` should be `File next`, not `String next`.

Comment: That will not work as itList is of type File, not String.

Comment: how about  conversion from file name to string and file path is already in string, or i should change to **Map<file.String>** ??

Comment: @PankajPathania `getName()` returns file name as a `String`, and `toString()` produces a file path, so `Map<String,String>` is fine.

Comment: is there any other way i can do that without using array?

Answer (score 1):

as said, you were calling `next` twice in each loop. It can also be resolved by using [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) streams.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
File folder = new File("F://fileIO/");
if (folder.isDirectory()) {
    map = Arrays.asList(folder.listFiles())
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(File::getName, 
                                          Object::toString));
    System.out.println(map);
} else {
    System.err.println("Something is wrong!");
}
```

---

```
Map<String, String> map = folder.isDirectory ? 
                          map = Arrays.asList(folder.listFiles())
                                      .stream()
                                      .collect(Collectors.toMap(File::getName, 
                                                              Object::toString)) :
                          new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but i think i need to work on lambda  now :)